# EditText in different OS/APIs text colors

Tags: android, android-edittext

In ICS, the background of EditText is a black color and in Gingerbread it is white. So the default EditText doesn't show in ICS but shows in GB.

Currently, I'm using:

```
            if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 11)
            editWeight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

But there must be a better way to write this. Thoughts? Beginner here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mess with the colors, the EditTexts will look fine (since they will contrast to whatever the default background is). However if you're setting colors manually set them for both the text AND the background!  I usually create my own 9patch background to use as the drawable for EditTexts, and then set the color of the text accordingly.

You'll also want to set the cursor drawable to null, or it will turn up being almost impossible to see in whatever version has the background color that it's similar to.